# How to use fputcsv()

Tags: php, fputcsv

I am working with `fputcsv()`. My below code is working.

```
$data = array(
            'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
            '123,456,789',
            '"aaa","bbb"',
        );

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    
foreach ($data as $line) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}

fclose($fp);
```

But below code is not working.

```
$data = array(
            'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
            '123,456,789',
            '"aaa","bbb"',
        );

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
    
foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);  // Here is the issue
}

fclose($fp);
```

I am getting empty output.

Comment: "code is not working" is not an adequate problem description. **How** is it not working? Empty output? A runtime error? Garbage output?

Comment: `fputcsv` expects an array as second parameter, not a string

Comment: @HonkderHase: The second parameter is an array , see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABWji.png

Comment: Not in your call ;) And sorry, but the code in the screenshot is not the same as here in the thread. Please don't post pictures of code...

Comment: The second piece of code is almost identical to the first Example in the docs: https://www.php.net/fputcsv   If that code does not work...

Comment: Yeah.. almost... but you're not getting the desired results with _almost_, do you? Let me ask: Do you _know_ the difference in these two code snippets?